# igraph; distance between nodes

Tags: igraph

I'm using igraph

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj2, mode = "directed") 

plot.igraph(g, vertex.size = 0.01, edge.arrow.size = 0.09, vertex.label.cex = 0.3, vertex.color = "white", vertex.shape = "none")
```

The problem that I have is that some nodes fall pretty close from each other and when I print it is hard to see some nodes.

I want to somehow to set a bigger distance between nodes that fall close (the central cluster of nodes, for example).

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use some layouts to extract the network and make it more readable. This can be done by different layouts, here an example for the fruchterman.reingold algorithm:

```
plot.igraph(g, layout =  layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.size = 0.01, edge.arrow.size = 0.09, vertex.label.cex = 0.3, vertex.color = "white", vertex.shape = "none")
```

Another example would be to use the `layout=layout.auto`. You have to look which layout fits better to your data.

You can read more about different layouts in the CRAN documentation [igraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/igraph.pdf)